# BeautifulSoup: Find any tag that matches one tag by name, or another tag by attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to find all tags that are either `<h1>` OR `<div class='abc'>`. I tried `bs.find_all(['h1', 'div'], attrs={'class': 'abc'})`, but this will ignore the `<h1>` tags: apparently, the `attrs` argument applies an AND condition to the search (meaning the tag must belong to the list of tag name AND have the given attribute, which the `<h1>` tags do not meet).

Can anyone suggest a fix to this? Thank you.

Comment: Can’t you just search twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can use [select](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from io import StringIO

data = """<html>
<body>
<h1>Test 1</h1>
<h2>Test 2</h2>
<div class='abc'><p>Test 3</p></div>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = bs(StringIO(data), 'html.parser')
print(soup.select('h1,div[class="abc"]'))
print(soup.find_all(['h1', 'div'], attrs={'class' : 'abc'}))
```

---

**output**

```
[<h1>Test 1</h1>, <div class="abc"><p>Test 3</p></div>]
[<div class="abc"><p>Test 3</p></div>]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenate two results like `bs.find_all('h1') + bs.find_all(['div', attrs={'class': 'abc'})` ?